# IOS-how can page-based Application load images?

Tags: ios, image

IOS-how can page-based Application load images?

Comment: What type of page-based?

Comment: Your question is far too broad and you don't show us the context or any work you've put in so far and where you are stuck. Please read [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for advice on how to write question that will give you good answers.

Comment: Your question is very unspecific. As if asking: How do I get from A to B... You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `UIImageView` to your view.